# while() and onclick

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, while-loop

I have this:

```
    while( $rowData = @mysql_fetch_assoc($selectRows2) )
    {
?>
<div id="stemmeto"><a href="#" id="thelink" onclick="window.parent.OpenVote(<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>, '<? echo $rowData['username']; ?>');">
<?php echo $rowData['username']; ?> </a></div>

<div id="stemme">
<a href="#" id="thelink" onclick="window.parent.OpenVote(<? echo $_GET['id']; ?>, '<? echo $rowData['username']; ?>');">
<? echo $rowData['stemme']; ?></div></a><br />
<?
    }
```

Now this should activate OpenVote function with (id, username) in the parent.window..
But for some reason this only works for first column, that comes out, nothing is happening when i click the others.. I have tried to remove that column, to check to see if its specially just that column, but it wasnt, its always the "first" column that echo´s out in the while(), that i can click on.. what should i do?

Here's the OpenVote script on the parent window(index.php)

```
function OpenVote(id, stemme)  {
  var postThisShit = 'battles/infoaboutvote.php?id='+id+'&stemme='+stemme;
  $.post(postThisShit, function(data){
        $(".showinfo").html(data).find(".getinfo").fadeIn("slow")
  });
  }
```

And the #thedialog on index.php:

```
<div id="thedialog" title="Showing..">
    <p class="showinfo">
        You shouldn't see this, something went wrong..
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id` attribute must be unique across your entire document. Your loop is creating multiple elements with the same `id`, which will cause behavior like you're describing when trying to interact with the elements. Try appending a unique value to the end of the `id`, such as `id-1`, `id-2`, `id-3`, etc.

Comment: Hi, are you talking about the <div id? or where? and how should i do like you say?

Comment: These three IDs are currently exactly the same for each iteration of the loop: `stemmeto`, `thelink`, and `stemme`. One way to make them unique is to use a counter variable to keep track of the loop iteration and append that number to the IDs each time, e.g., in pseduocode: `<? $counter = 0; ?> /* start loop */ <div id="stemme-<? echo $counter; ?>">...</div> <? $counter++; ?> /* end loop */`

Comment: Any id. Whenever you have <element id="element_id">, no other element can share that id. So like jimmy says, since your loop repeats the id="stemmeto", id="stemme" and id="thelink" over and over, for each item in $rowData, your javascript only works on the first id it encounters with that name.

if $rowData is returning a database record, try appending the record id to your ids:

<div id="stemmeto_<?php echo $rowData['id'] ?>"><a href="#" id="thelink_<?php echo $rowData['id'] ?>" ...

Comment: But if you do like that with "thelink" then my other function: $('#thelink').click(function(){ 
window.parent.$('div#thedialog').dialog('open'); wont work

Comment: So change `thelink` from an ID to a class.

Comment: like this:
$('.thelink').click(function(){ window.parent.$('div#thedialog').dialog('open'); ?